# .ipynb checkpoint files misplaced

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, visual-studio-code

I work with Jupyter Notebooks with [VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/) as my editor. I have noticed that my checkpoint files are not being properly saved in the `.ipynb_checkpoints` folder as should be.

To illustrate, I made a notebook called `test.ipynb`, and after starting to work on it (added a few lines of code), the following notebooks were autogenerated in the same directory (not in the `.ipynb_checkpoints` folder):

```
test-d636f411-dc52-42c3-8fd5-3ff98a144a25.ipynb
test-804fd168-59a6-40f4-bdb1-fcf1b2fe899f.ipynb
test-1dbb5747-9833-40cb-a382-4a42cae0008a.ipynb
```

This happens with all my notebooks and, as a result, crowds my working space. I keep manually deleting these redundant files (which by the way have no code in them), but I think there may be something wrong with my settings.

Has anyone experienced this before and how did you solve it? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce your problem, but it could be an issue with the `Jupyter Notebook`.

Some people have met this kind of problem, you can refer to [this page](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/6510) for more details.

Could you try to install another version of the `Jupyter Notebook` to make a try?

Comment: Thank you! I'd try this suggestion. The link to the page (on similar problems) isn't going through though.

Comment: @Subomi Very sorry for that, I had updated the link.

Comment: not yet. I can see that the link works but haven't seen any solution posted.

Comment: @Subomi It still not working when you install an older version of the Python Extension?

Comment: I checked the page link you attached and didn't see that as a suggested solution but I will try. I'm careful not to change my VS code settings as it was a bit of a hassle getting it to work on the remote machine.